# Capital Upsilon used similarly to sigma summation notation? What does this mean?

Tags: logic, notation

I've come across this notation in some logic notes regarding Henkin's proof of completeness:

$W_{LC} = \Upsilon_{i=0}^{\infty} W_{LC(i)}$

I believe the character is an upsilon, although I suppose it could be an uppercase Y. It's not explained at all, I've never seen it before, and evidently no one else on earth has either because I can't find anything about it online. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Y is right next to U on QWERTY keyboards.  Maybe it is a typo for U (union)?

Comment: More context is necessary but my guess would also by $U$ for $\cup$. What are the $W_{LC(i)}$'s?

Comment: I doubt it is a Typo as it appears a few times. The $W_{LC(i)}$'s are sets of well-formed-formulas in an expanded versions of the first-order language L that are used in Henkin's proof of completeness.

Comment: What is $W_{LC}$ without an $i$? It seems like it can't be a sum because you don't add sets of wffs. You do sometimes union them though.

Comment: Do you have a link to the notes? That would be very helpful

Comment: The language LC is obtained by adding an infinite set of constants $\{c_{0},c_{1},...\}$ to the language L. $W_{LC}$ is the set of wffs in LC. The $W_{LC(i)}$'s are kind of like subsets of $W_{LC}$, with each one obtained by adding a subset of the infinite set of constants to L.

Comment: Did you see this symbol in a pdf file issued from a $\LaTeX$ file or in a Microsoft Word or Powerpoint file? It looks to me like a corrupted character.

Comment: My first guess is that this symbol means union (just like $\bigcup$) but with the added information that the sets whose union is being formed constitute an increasing sequence.